# Spring cross context file bean auto wire

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I am currently using spring web mvc framework. And I have my web.xml/servlet-context.xml/each layer xml files in following structure:

```
web.xml -> servlet-context.xml ---imports-->service-applicationContext.xml
                               ---imports-->integration-applicationContext.xml
                               ---imports-->web-applicationContext.xml
```

in the service/integration/web-applicationContext.xml file, I do a component scan to the corresponding package.

But the problem is, when I try to auto wire the DAO class in the service layer, spring complains no such bean. But I think in servlet-context.xml since all three files are imported, they should be able to share the context or should I do something else to configure it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you have your DAO class annotated so that Spring can scan it.
2. If you do not annotate them than declare them in application context file.

Comment: sorry, actually its just my mistake that I use a wrong import file instead of the integration-applicationContext.xml.

Comment: yes, I use a wrong import name by mistake and seems spring dont really report a missing imports

Answer (score 0):

The above pattern is actually working.

Just make sure the name is correct since missing imports file in bean folder will fail silently